# Use Group by in conjunction with Order by is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to get the first transaction in the history of all accounts belonging to an user_id. For example, in the case of the user_id = 12656 the older transaction of the  account_id = 1553 could be the 064d1777-3783 but in the case of the account 1554, the oldest tx is 0cb4cfb2-44a2

This is a fragment of the table "order"

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ user_id ║ account_id ║ order_id ║ status   ║ test  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12656   ║ 1553       ║ 1234     ║ CAPTURED ║ false ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12656   ║ 1554       ║ 5678     ║ CAPTURED ║ false ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12656   ║ 1554       ║ 91011    ║ PENDING  ║ false ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12659   ║ 1556       ║ 176344   ║ PENDING  ║ true  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12660   ║ 1557       ║ 261677   ║ CAPTURED ║ false ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12661   ║ 1558       ║ 347010   ║ CAPTURED ║ true  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12662   ║ 1559       ║ 432343   ║ CAPTURED ║ false ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 12663   ║ 1560       ║ 517676   ║ CAPTURED ║ false ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

the same for table "transaction"

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ user_id ║ account_id ║ order_id ║ transaction_id ║ creation_date           ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12656   ║ 1553       ║ 1234     ║ 064d1777-3783  ║ 2012-10-03 00:54:35.042 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12656   ║ 1554       ║ 5678     ║ 0cb4cfb2-44a2  ║ 2012-05-06 06:33:13.171 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12656   ║ 1554       ║ 91011    ║ 164494f1-3226  ║ 2012-05-29 00:49:27.611 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12659   ║ 1556       ║ 176344   ║ 064d1777-3784  ║ 2012-07-25 05:32:48.056 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12660   ║ 1557       ║ 261677   ║ 0cb4cfb2-44a3  ║ 2012-04-11 00:42:17.176 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12661   ║ 1558       ║ 347010   ║ 164494f1-3227  ║ 2012-05-16 08:01:38.666 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12662   ║ 1559       ║ 432343   ║ 064d1777-3785  ║ 2012-04-11 00:48:38.499 ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 12663   ║ 1560       ║ 517676   ║ 0cb4cfb2-44a4  ║ 2012-05-06 06:39:33.44  ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

and I coded the following query:

```
SELECT order.account_id, order.user_id, tx.transaction_id, MIN(tx.creation_date) AS first_transaction  
FROM transaction AS tx
 INNER JOIN order AS order ON tx.order_id = order.order_id  
WHERE order.test = 'false' 
 AND order.status = 'CAPTURED' 
GROUP BY order.account_id, order.user_id, tx.transaction_id
```

But this isn't working and I want to know why. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (o.account_id, o.user_id) o.account_id, o.user_id, 
       tx.transaction_id, tx.creation_date AS first_transaction  
FROM transaction tx INNER JOIN
     order o
     ON tx.order_id = o.order_id  
WHERE o.test = 'false' AND o.status = 'CAPTURED' 
ORDER BY o.account_id, o.user_id, tx.creation_date ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Why is this necessary?

Comment: @JuanDavid . . . You want one row per `account_id`/`user_id` with the information from the first transaction.  `distinct on` does exactly that, with the right `order by` clause.